# How to count all the unique and total rows within a database for all tables using Spark/Pyspark

Tags: sql, database, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I want to count all the unique and total rows for all tables within a Hive database for our team to clean up some of the tables.

There is no fancy code, I am running a for loop using Spark Cluster and Pyspark api function to do that, below is my pseudo code:

I also tried to add `time.sleep` to relieve the computation power but that didn't work.

```
for table in all_table:

    get 
        table_name, 
        table_columns,
        table_name_unique_count,
        table_name_total_count 
    using Spark.SQL

    print(table_name, 
          table_columns, 
          table_name_unique_count, 
          table_name_total_count)

    append 
        table_name, 
        table_columns,
        table_name_unique_count,
        table_name_total_count 
    to the lists

    time.sleep(5)

combine the lists to create a dataframe
```

The process is taking a really long time because within our database there are 900 tables, what can I do to improve so I can this task complete? I am new to SQL, Spark and Pyspark, any suggestion is appreciated here!

Comment: Where is the SQL here?

Comment: do the operations within the db itself and bring the resolved data to spark, if you're not already doing that.

Comment: can you checkwith hive admin for metadata tables. They have counts... since you are doing a count(), it takes time. if you cant, you can also write a simple shell script to check size of files of tables.

Comment: you can run a `describe formatted <hivedb>.<hivetbl>` to get the statistics - given the metadata is already stored